# Cypress test returning "TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of undefined" when trying to call a method in the same page object class with 'this'

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress

I have following test class in cypress/integration/todo-actions.spec.js,

```
    /// <reference types="cypress" />

import { TodoPage } from "../page-object/TodoPage"

describe('todo actions test', () => {
    const todoPage = new TodoPage
    const todoText = 'hello'

    beforeEach(() => {
        todoPage.navigateDelay()
        todoPage.addToDo(todoText)
    })

    it('add to do', () => {
        todoPage.verifyTodoText(todoText)
        todoPage.verifyTodoIsNotSelected(1)
    })
})
```

It is referring the 'todoPage.verifyTodoIsNotSelected' the method in the cypress/page-object.js class. That class has an assertion which is referring to another method in the same class.

```
export class TodoPage{
    navigate() {
        cy.visit('http://todomvc-app-for-testing.surge.sh/')
    }

    navigateDelay() {
        cy.visit('http://todomvc-app-for-testing.surge.sh/?delay-new-todo=4000')
    }

    addToDo(todoText){
        cy.get('.new-todo', {timeout:6000}).type(todoText + '{enter}')
    }

    getTodo(index){
        cy.get('li:nth-child('+index+') > .view > .toggle')
    }

    selectToDo(index){
        this.getTodo(index).click()
    }

    clearToDo(){
        cy.contains('Clear completed').click()
    }

    filterAll(){
        cy.get(':nth-child(1) > a').click()
    }

    filterActive(){
        cy.get(':nth-child(2) > a').click()
    }

    filterCompleted(){
        cy.get(':nth-child(3) > a').click()
    }

    //assertions start
    verifyTodoIsNotSelected(index){
        this.getTodo(index).should('not.be.checked')
    }

    verfyTodoIsSelected(index){
        this.getTodo(index).should('be.checked')
    }

    verifyTodoText(todoText){
        cy.get('label').should('have.text',todoText)
    }

    verifyTodoMarkCompleted(){
        cy.get('label').should('have.css','text-decoration-line','line-through')
    }

    verifyClearTodo(){
        cy.get('.todo-list').should('not.have.descendants','li')
    }

    verifyTodoCount(count){
        cy.get('.todo-list li').should('have.length', count)
    }
}
```

But when I ran the test, it fails with following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of undefined
```

I tried the following and it passed, But I want to know why the above is failed?

```
verifyTodoIsNotSelected(index){
    cy.get('li:nth-child('+index+') > .view > .toggle').should('not.be.checked')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the cy.get method here

```
getTodo(index){
        return cy.get('li:nth-child('+index+') > .view > .toggle')
}
```